# ZF2 PDO error when loading Action from console

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, console, zend-framework2

I have an application that works correctly when accessed from a browser, I can query PostgreSQL without any problems but when I try to load it via the console I get the error:

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException
Connect Error: could not find driver
```

The routing, controller and action load correctly as long as I don't try to query the database.

Is there anything I'm missing, maybe something else I need to set when trying to query the DB from the console?

From the console I run it via `php /web/public/index.php action` which works until I add the DB calls.

//UPDATE

My global.php looks like:

```
'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'            => 'pgsql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),
 ),
 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
```

Comment: it looks like you have a configuration issue. can you post its contents?

Comment: @PAlphen where should I add that?

Comment: change the following according to zf2 documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html

`'driver' => 'Pdo_Pgsql',`

Comment: @PAlphen same error `Connect Error: could not find driver`

Comment: did you configured different db adapters for console and http requests?
did you have a super global (for example`$_SERVER`) defined in one of your config files?

Comment: @PAlphen no, not at all, it's just my global.php configuring it all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98415/discussion-between-palphen-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for brevity;

After discussion on chat, turns out server was configured to handle http and console requests over different PHP binary's. Changing the php path solved the problem.